# If Then Statement with dates

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am programming a command button so that it may give me the assets that were sold between two dates.

**A run time error 13: mismatch** currently appears when i run the code.

I changed the `If Then` statement  but i still get the same error. Below is an example of what i am trying to accomplish with the button. I want the code to look through all the dates in the sheet. Then those rows that are in-between the two dates are to be copied then pasted into another sheet.

```
| Asset#    | Asset Name S# | Sold     |
|-----------|---------------|----------|
| 4555#1202 | Scissor Lift  | 12/15/12 |
| 4898#1204 | Light Tower   | 11/12/15 |
```

This is the code I'm running for the command button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton9_Click() 

    Worksheets("Paste2").Rows("2:1000").Delete

    Dim erow As Long, start As Date, enddt As Date

    x = 2

    '*The 12 represents the column which contains the date for when the asset was sold*

    Do While Worksheets("Asset Info").Cells(x, 12) <> ""

        start = DateValue("October 1,2016")
        enddt = DateValue("October 31,2016")

        If Worksheets("Asset Info").Range("L1:L2500") > start And Worksheets("Asset Info").Range("L1:L2500") < enddt Then  '*This is where the error occurs in the code*        

            Worksheets("Asset Info").Rows(x).Copy
            Worksheets("Paste2").Activate

            erow = Worksheets("Paste2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row        
            ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Paste2").Rows(erow)    
        End If

        Worksheets("Paste2").Activate       
        x = x + 1    

    Loop    

    Worksheets("Paste2").Activate
End Sub
```

Any suggestions will greatly be appreciated.

[an example of sheet im trying to copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5coP.png)

Other form for the command button

```
`Worksheets("Paste2").Rows("2:1000").Delete


Dim erow As Long, LastRow As Long, start As Date, enddt As Date

LastRow = Workheets("Asset Info").Cells(Workheets("Asset Info").Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To LastRow

    start = DateValue("October 1,2016")
    enddt = DateValue("October 31,2016")

    If Worksheets("Asset Info").Cells(x, 12).Value <> "" > start And Worksheets("Asset Info").Cells(x, 12).Value <> "" < enddt Then


        Worksheets("Asset Info").Rows(x).Copy
        Worksheets("Paste2").Activate

        erow = Worksheets("Paste2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Paste2").Rows(erow)

   End If
Next x

End Sub`
```

Comment: I have a suggestion: Insert an Excel table, then you will have access to its auto filter easily, filter the columns as you want and then copy the visible cells of the table body into a new sheet.

Comment: Is there actually a sheet called "Assets Info" as well as "Asset Info" ? This would be a different error code none the less. And please use Option Explicit at the top of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now tried and tested the following code and it should do what you expect it to:

```
Sheets("Paste2").Rows("2:1000").Delete

Dim erow As Long, start As Date, enddt As Date

LastRow = Sheets("Asset Info").Cells(Sheets("Asset Info").Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To LastRow
    start = DateValue("October 1,2016")
    enddt = DateValue("October 31,2016")

    If Sheets("Asset Info").Cells(x, 12).Value > start And Sheets("Asset Info").Cells(x, 12).Value < enddt Then
        Sheets("Asset Info").Rows(x).Copy
        erow = Sheets("Paste2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Sheets("Paste2").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Paste2").Rows(erow)
   End If
Next x
```

Comment: The change works for a few of the asset but i get an error code for

Comment: Do While Worksheets("Asset Info").Cells(x, 12) <> "" this part of the code which tell me a mismatch error run time error 13

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: I changed the part of the code as suggested but the command doesnt even run. I put the new code in the original post. @Xabier

Comment: Sorry just noticed I missed the cell reference on the IF statement, please have a look at my updated answer,..

Comment: I changed the cell reference and when i go to execute the button nothing happens.

Comment: You mistyped the following: If Worksheets("Assest Info").Cells(x, 12).Value <> "" > start And 
Worksheets("Assest Info").Cells(x, 12).Value <> "" < enddt Then

Comment: I changed the mistype but it still won't run for some reason

Comment: I've updated my answer with the full code, I've tried and tested it and it works for me, please give it a try and let me know how you get on...

Comment: Run Time error "1004": Application defined or object defined error for the LastRow=Worksheets("Asset Info")......

Comment: Adrian, please try replacing your code with my updated answer, where you have Worksheets("Assest Info") should be written as Sheets("Assest Info")

Comment: Let me send you a copy of the workbook to see what the may problem may be. My spelling of the sheets are correct so Im lost where the problem may lie

Comment: Before you do that @Adrian, please try replacing the code for your command button with my answer, as I've updated it and it should work for you now... Also instead of Worksheets("Asset Info") it should be Sheets("Asset Info"), as well as a couple more syntax errors you had in your code.

Comment: I forget to mention on the last comment that i did replace my code with your code and nothing unfortunately.

Comment: Still nothing unfortunately

Comment: Well there must be something else at play here because the code in my answer worked for me, so I'm at a loss at the moment... Send us a copy of your workbook and I will give it a try...

Comment: How do i go about that im new to stack overflow and i dont see an option to atttach a file

Comment: Upload the workbook to something like Google Drive or Dropbox and then include that link in your comment...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzF5FppySheBRXJVLXltTVdyejZtRHUzRU9iWDMwa0hER29B/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your error was not with the code I gave you but with the VLookup on the column L, I've now fixed that and you can find the spreadsheet on the following link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aYbSZ-6nQoX6mLJ6clHMUTFv_mxa1DWN

Comment: No worries, just to be clear, you were trying to lookup values that were giving you #N/A, then you were trying to check if this value falls between two dates, as such the error occurred, by wrapping you Vlookup with IFerror, then you can alter the result of #N/A to NULL, this will help you when checking if this falls between two dates... Anyways happy to help! :)